# how to refresh page when html5 audio tag ends play

Tags: html

I got this html5 code but the javascript doesn't seem to be working...

What I want to do is:

1. AutoPlay an audio file when page loads
2. When the file ends, refresh the page...

Cannot seem to get this working...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function playVideo(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.play();
    video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        window.location = 'http://localhost/sampleAudio22.html';
    });
}
</script>

<audio controls id="video" width="770" height="882" onclick="playVideo()">
    <source src="arabic/nancy_ajram-atabtab.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for "autoplay".

```
<audio controls id="video" width="770" height="882" autoplay>
    <source src="arabic/nancy_ajram-atabtab.mp3" />
</audio>
```

try this for second.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        window.location = 'http://localhost/sampleAudio22.html';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<audio controls id="video" width="770" height="882" autoplay>
    <source src="arabic/nancy_ajram-atabtab.mp3" />
</audio>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',function(){
        window.location = 'http://localhost/sampleAudio22.html';
    });
</script>
```